# How to show html not escaped?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, escaping

I have an API that return a string that represent the body of a email, so it is html:

e.g

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head> ...
```

How can I let the browser interpret it and render the email in my javascript application, in a container (a div or whatever)?

Comment: Type the URL of the API into the browser's address bar.

Comment: So what exactly are you currently doing that's *not* working...?

Comment: @deceze I am receive the string, and I want that my javascript app render the email in a container (a div or whatever..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert the text into the innerHTML of some element on your page.

```
var emailBody = <get the raw html from the api>;
document.getElementById("someDiv").innerHTML = emailBody;
```

Comment: But the api returns me a string, because it returns me a JSON with a body property, with a string in it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. You have the HTML body of the email as a string, no? So just set the innerHTML of some div on your page to that string.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the this it was the same of put the variable in my template, like I was doing, but it turns out the wasn't so! thanks!